# Limit unlink to one only

Tags: php

Aloha, I have a download button and when the image is downloaded it`s dispalyed using session (path).  I then delete the picture that was used before, but when the name of the image is the same, "unlink($_SESSION['picture']);" deletes both of them- I want to delete ony one each time... Something like this "unlink($_SESSION['picture'] < 1);" which doesn't work.
Please Help:), Aloha

And here's the code which saves the picture..

```
session_start();

$filename    = $_FILES["picture"]["tmp_name"];
$destination = "upload/" . $_FILES["picture"]["name"]; 
move_uploaded_file($filename, $destination); //save uploaded picture in your directory
$_SESSION['picture'] = $destination;
```

Comment: it's because of unicity that it will be better to give the name of the record and store inside the db the "real" name of the file. This way you will unset only one image without trouble.

Comment: As example, if you use db, you can have a field for real file name and use the unicity of  db record (as example an auto-increment field) to name the file on the filesystem =)

Comment: And to do that, do I just need to change "move_ipload_file" to "mysql insert" ?

Comment: no, you need to do both have a record for a file and get the file from the db

Comment: One more question, If I insert the image "path" to mysql, when I delete it using mysql, will the image in upload file still be there?

Comment: Yes, it's better to insert to db before uploading the file (the filename on file system will be something return by db with a query). When unlink before unlink the file from filesystem, if true then delete from db (as example).

Comment: So I need to delete image from mysql and file?

Comment: you are not uploading the image on the db. Only it's real name =), wait and i'll write an answer

Answer (score 0):

Has we've said.
Start with uploading the file

```
session_start();

$filename    = $_FILES["picture"]["tmp_name"];
//Cutted the file name from the $destination
$destination = "upload/"; 

//Insert Into DB the info.
//Query Similar To
$sql = "INSERT INTO mytable (filename) VALUES (".$filename.")";

//Get from DB the ID generated.
$sql2 = "SELECT id FROM mytable WHERE filename = '".$filename."'";
//Fetch the data into a $filenameNew var

move_uploaded_file($filename, $destination.$filenameNew); //save uploaded picture in your directory with the db id

$_SESSION['picture'] = $destination.$filenameNew;
```

On delete instead

```
 $sql2 = "SELECT id FROM mytable WHERE ..."; //Get the id name of the file
//put id on a var - $toUnlink
unlink($toUnlink);

$sqlDelete = "DELETE FROM mytable WHERE id = '".$toUnlink."'";
```

This is a working chain. You need to some work to make it works correctly based on your application.

Comment: Hi mate, what's the //Fetch the data into a $filenameNew var ?

Comment: ok, and what is //Cutted the file name from the $destination ?

Comment: To change the file on upload. You use $destination = "upload/" . $_FILES["picture"]["name"]; . If you do delete what is it after the string ("upload/") you have the folder inside a var, i then use that on concatenation with the (new) $filenameNew to give it a new name on upload

Comment: Could you please look at my jsfiddle here's the link:http://jsfiddle.net/35mu3ysk/    Please corrct me:)